# Mean calculation from dataframe columns with pyspark

Tags: math, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, calculated-columns

I'm looking for solution how to do following calculation without conversion from spark df to pandas df:

`mean = sum(df[A]*df[B])/sum(df[B])`

Calculation based on selected columns in spark dataframe can be done by splitting it in pieces like:
`new_col = df[A]*df[B]`
 `new_col = sum(new_col)`
 `new_col2 = sum(df[B])`
`mean = new_col/new_col2`
But I hope there are more sophisticated ways to do that. Perhaps by using spark .withColumn function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a new column with the product and then aggregate:

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df = spark.createDataFrame(data=[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3], [1, 2, 3]], schema=["A", "B", "C"])

mean = (
    df
    .withColumn("AB", F.col("A") * F.col("B"))
    .groupBy()
    .agg(F.mean("AB").alias("AB"), F.mean("B").alias("B"))
    .withColumn("mean", F.col("AB") / F.col("B"))
)

mean.show()
```